# Text join too many charaters - regular expressions too big

Tags: google-sheets

I am joinin cells with TEXTJOIN but sometimes there are too many charaters and it is giving me a #VALUE error.

I have tried to use a formula like this but it says that a regular expression cannot be too big

=split(REGEXREPLACE(textjoin("
", TRUE,B2:K2),"^.{5000}", "$0 "), " ")

Comment: i've encountered this problem before and found help here on Stackoverflow. Can't find it now but it entailed using the query function instead of textjoin.

Comment: `Textjoin()` has character limitation. May be it 50,000. So, it can't handle more that 50,000 character.

Comment: @a-burge thanks, I will have a search and see if I can find it.

Comment: @Harun24HR okay then I will probably have to break it up somehow. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

to join huge dataset use this:

```
=QUERY(FLATTEN(B2:K2);;9^9)
```

a space is added automatically between cells so you can split it on spaces or if that is not desirable you can convert spaces before query to some unique symbol, split it on spaces and again substitute unique symbol into spaces